# In Mdriven Turnkey what is meant by the various service pricing elements?

Tags: mdriven

I have watched the pricing video here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tmxXNeqflzM
and have been studying the pricing quote calculator at: 
https://licenseandticket.azurewebsites.net/Turnkey/AngularApp#/PriceQuoteWhatIf

How are the following elements defined & quantified?

"Inclusive Add Ons?"

"Better CPU & RAM?"

"Data out from Site?" Does this include large cross-referenced documents stored in a filesystem outside the main database?

"Priority Support?"

"Control Core Deployment?"

"Region Placement?"

"Always On?"

"MDriven Framework Option?"

"History Server Option?"

How does licensing of MDriven designer work if I have the free version (allowing 50 classes) and I want to use more classes? The Turnkey pricing seems to suggest that this is included but how would I unlock the 50 class limit?

Would costs be reduced if I am hosting on my own Azure account?

Finally, how would one calculate the cost for a SaaS where each tenant has their own database?

Many Thanks.

ps: Perhaps it would be a good idea to add this information to the the quote calculator form?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question. Contact their sales team for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are all good questions and I will update the wiki page here https://wiki.mdriven.net/index.php/Pricing